# Spring: mvn clean tomcat:run works on command line but not IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a Maven controller Spring web app and it runs fine on the command line with `mvn clean tomcat:run` but I can't get it to work with a Run/Debug Configuration. I get a long list of autowire dependencies failures ending with:

> ...Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.mycompany.config.DataSourceConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$543b87de]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Here is the offending class:

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {


    //change PACKAGE_TO_SCAN
    private static final String PACKAGE_TO_SCAN = "com.mycompany"; 
    private static final int MODE_DEV = 0;
    private static final int MODE_STG = 1;
    private static final int MODE_PROD = 2;


    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private int environment = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT"));

    private String dburl = System.getenv("UMWORKFLOW_DATABASE_URL");
    private String dbuser = System.getenv("UMWORKFLOW_DATABASE_USER");
    private String dbpass = System.getenv("UMWORKFLOW_DATABASE_PASSWORD");



    public DataSourceConfig(){

    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="close")
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException, PropertyVetoException {

        ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();



        ds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setMinPoolSize(1);
        ds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        ds.setAcquireIncrement(1);
        ds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(300);
        ds.setMaxStatements(0);
        ds.setCheckoutTimeout(100);

        ds.setJdbcUrl(dburl);
        ds.setUser(dbuser);
        ds.setPassword(dbpass);

        return ds;

    }

    @Bean
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws URISyntaxException, PropertyVetoException {

        AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sf = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
        sf.setDataSource(dataSource());
        String[] packageToScan = new String[1];
        packageToScan[0] = PACKAGE_TO_SCAN;
        sf.setPackagesToScan(packageToScan);
        Properties hibProp = new Properties();
        hibProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");


        //modes create, create-drop, update, validate
        if( environment == MODE_DEV) {

            hibProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        } else if ( environment == MODE_STG) {

            hibProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        } else {

            hibProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        }


        sf.setHibernateProperties(hibProp);
        return sf;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system property `ENVIRONMENT` seems to be custom.

```
private int environment = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT"));
```

So `System.getenv()` is returning `null` and causing the `IllegalArgumentException`. You will need to set that property in your `run/debug` configuration.